# Can multiple accounts use the DLC on the Resident Evil Origins Collection?

Tags: ps4, resident-evil-2002

I bought the new collection of *Resident Evil* for PS4. As I pre-purchased it, the store gave me an additional DLC code that provides clothing for the main characters.

I have two accounts on my PS4: my main account and one for my girlfriend.

What I want to know is: if I activate the DLC code on one account, will I be able to use the DLC on both accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should activate the DLC on your main account (i.e. your account, not your girlfriends). If your account has been activated as "Primary" for that console, you should have no issues sharing the DLC with the other account(s).